# Is it a good idea to have multiple git repos inside other repo?

Tags: git

My question is not about possibility. I know that it is possible and read on the same site that it is called submodules.

During a project I realized that we had developed several reusable components which others could use and hence we created multiple projects on gihub and put appropriate files into them. However in the main project we had a single git repository.

Over the period of time we realized some of the projects on github were forked by others and improved as well. Had we created multiple repos inside our main project we could have easily pulled in the changes instead of manually copying the files.

Since I have not experience managing large and multiple projects with git I would like to know if it is standard practice worth encouraging to have multiple git repositories inside a single large repository.

Are there any trade offs ? Any important points we need to take into consideration ?

Answer (score 1):

That's where the concept of [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) come in, as you noticed.

To exemplify this situation, I'm gonna use the [Kohana Framework](http://github.com/kohana/kohana), a PHP full-stack framework for web applications.

The Kohana structure is this:

- system (Kohana's core)
- modules (Kohana's official modules)

You can see that the system directory actually corresponds to a single repository, the [core](http://github.com/kohana/core), and the modules directory has multiple modules, each one with its own repository, to represent a specific reusable feature, for instance, [auth](http://github.com/kohana/auth), [database](http://github.com/kohana/database) and [orm](http://github.com/kohana/orm).

Kohana is a big project, and that approach is really good on keeping their philosophy.